# Determine envelopes for the payloads?

Tags: communication-satellite, payload, environment, optical, transport

I am a mechanical engineer who is trying to expand my domain knowledge in aerospace and am currently reading a book to increase my understanding of it. I am mostly interested in studying the design of STS (Space transport system). Can anyone please help me through the below-mentioned question that I am not able to understand.

**What are the most important factors to determine envelopes for the mechanical environment of the payload during a flight on a launcher?** what different kinds of loads will there be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For STS payload induced enviroments, grab yourself a copy of the [Space Shuttle User's Handbook](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19770081124.pdf) and you will find plenty of data starting on page 31 of the pdf.

Vibration, noise, thermal, pressure (and lack thereof), all the usual suspects.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have lent me something equivalent to gold! Thanks a lot! I am currently going through the handbook.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, and welcome to space stack exchange!

Comment: I am through the factors influencing the mechanical environment. Out of the four most important factors (vibration, thermal, noise, and pressure), which one would be the most critical on which I should emphasize? As per the handbook, thermal and pressure are quite critical but can we really rank them?


For my future simulation case study, I would also like to consider some external environmental conditions (apart from the mechanical environment) that should also be defined for the payload (For e.g. cooling system, etc.). Do you have any recommendations?